# Keep application-specific fields synced with database

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have a `GameConsole` model :

```
public class GameConsole
{
    public int ID { get; protected set; } = 0;
    public string Identifier { get; protected set; } = "GameConsole";
    
    public List<string> ValidInputs { get; set; } = new List<string>(8);
    public Dictionary<string, InputAxis> InputAxesMap { get; protected set; } = new Dictionary<string, InputAxis>(8);
    public Dictionary<string, InputButton> InputButtonMap { get; protected set; } = new Dictionary<string, InputButton>(32);
    
    public string ValidInputsStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string InputAxesMapStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string InputButtonMapStr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I need `ValidInputs`, `InputAxesMap`, and `InputButtonMap` stored in an SQLite database. I've done this by serializing to JSON in their respective `ValidInputsStr`, `InputAxesMapStr`, and `InputButtonMapStr` fields.

However, I need to use these lists and dictionaries in the application. But each time I open the database context, `ValidInputs`, `InputAxesMap`, and `InputButtonMap` don't contain the data (unless I deserialize them from the JSON strings).

```
using (MyDatabaseContext context = new MyDatabaseContext(databasePath))
{
    GameConsole gmConsole = context.Consoles.First((console) => console.Identifier == "GC");
    Console.WriteLine(gmConsole.InputButtonMap.Count); //Prints 0
    gmConsole.ReadInJSONFields(); //This is what I want to eliminate
    Console.WriteLine(gmConsole.InputButtonMap.Count); //Has the proper data after reading from JSON
}
```

This is inconvenient considering there will be more objects in the future. How can I have everything be read and written directly to and from the database, and have these fields be populated?

An example `GameConsole` in JSON form:

```
{
  "Identifier": "GC",
  "ValidInputs": [
    "left",
    "up",
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "InputAxesMap": {
    "left": {
      "AxisVal": 0,
      "MinAxisVal": 0.0,
      "MaxAxisVal": -1.0,
      "MaxPercentPressed": 100
    },
    "up": {
      "AxisVal": 1,
      "MinAxisVal": 0.0,
      "MaxAxisVal": -1.0,
      "MaxPercentPressed": 100
    },
  "InputButtonMap": {
    "a": {
      "ButtonVal": 0
    },
    "b": {
      "ButtonVal": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I imagine those fields will never have less or more elements, but rather always 8/32 as your code shows. Could you not another table for each field and have a column for each value? Or another way would be one row per item and a column with the type, if you could have more than 8/32 maps. Because, the way this is done, you're mixing a relational database with a document database, and it's confusing to say the least

Comment: 8/32 is just the initial capacity. It's possible to add and remove from those collections.